# set docker-machine variables using a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-machine

I have a script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

The goal is to automate the setting of variables like

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
export DOCKER_HOST
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME
```

But when I check afterwards, the variables are not set. This is not the case if I run each `export` command manually. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`export` makes variables available **only to the active shell session**. If you want them to persist through sessions, you must add them to your bash profile:

```
docker-machine env default >> ~/.bash_profile
```

This way, the variables will be available in all future shell sessions. Make sure to restart the shell after executing the command.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the environment set in your current shell you need to "source" the script rather than run it.

When you run a script, the variables will be set in the child `bash` processes environment and will not exist once that script/process dies.

```
$ ./machine.sh
DOCKER_HOST is tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
$ echo "[$DOCKER_HOST]"
[]
```

When you source a script, the variables will be set in your current environment

```
$ . machine.sh
DOCKER_HOST is tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
$ echo "[$DOCKER_HOST]"
[tcp://192.168.99.100:2376]
```